# G is a non-trivial $SRG-(n,k,\lambda,\mu)$, show $k^2>nmin(\lambda,\mu)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I read a proof for this bound in one of Babai's papers from the 80's for the general hypergraph bound. But has anyone seen a simpler proof? Show $k^2>n*min(\lambda,\mu)$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks @cpiegore, this is not an exam question or unsolved problem, it is a published result. I'm just looking for different ideas or counting arguments for this bound.

Comment: The issue is that words like "simpler" are subjective: simpler in what way? Do you have any reason to believe that there is a simpler proof? What do you understand about the existing proof? Is there some aspect of the proof that you find confusing? What specific paper did the proof come from?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you are referring to appears in *On the Automorphism Groups of Strongly Regular Graphs*, and the proof you are referring to appears to come from the reference *On The Complexity Of Canonical Labelling Of Strongly Regular Graphs*, both by Babai.

Notice in the first paper, we require $k \leq \frac{(n − 1)}{2}$. If not, we can take the complement and with some steps get the required result.

This inequalities can actually be produced in many many other ways, I will leave that as an exercise to you. I will attempt to explain the proof in the latter paper and hopefully it helps. If you understood it, it should not be difficult to translate it to the more specific case of the strongly regular graphs.

Let me quote the theorem from the paper;

> Let $1\leq d< r<n $ be integers, $|V| = n$ and  $H = (V,\mathcal{F})$
> be a nonempty $t-$regular, $r-$ uniform hypergraph such that $E\cap F \geq d$  for any $E,F\in \mathcal{F}$. Then, $r^2>nd$.

Let's explain a few terms:

In a hypergraph, each hyperedge can have multiple vertices. The degree of aa vertex is counted by the number of hyperedges it is contained within and a uniform hypergraph means each hyperedge contains the same number of vertices.

Translating it to the strongly regular graph context, since each hyperedge contains precisely $r$ vertices, and from our assumption, we can assign each hyperedge to be the valency of some vertex. (why is this possible? what is the meaning of a uniform hypergraph, and how do we translate to the context of strongly regular graphs?).

$E\cap F \geq d$ means any two hyperedges have at least $d$ vertices in common. In the language of graphs, any two edges have at least $d$ neighbours in common. In the case of strongly regular graphs, this can only be $\lambda$ or $\mu$, which is how the inequality comes about.

How was the inequality proved? Through a counting argument!

Given a vertex and hyperedge pair $(v,F)$, we find the number of vertices (including multiplicities) that are in $F$ but also in some other hyperedge $E$ in two ways.

1. Each hyperedge has $r$ vertices (regular) and each of these vertices
   appear in $t-1$ other hyperedges (uniform).
2. There are $|\mathcal{F}| - 1$ other hyperedges, and each of them have at most $d$ vertices in common with $F$.

This gives us the inequality $r(t-1) \geq (|\mathcal{F}| - 1 )d = (\frac{tn}{r} - 1)d$.

Why $|\mathcal{F}| = \frac{tn}{r}$ is a simple counting argument left as an exercise.

We can rearrange this to

$$t(r^2-nd) \geq r(r-d).$$

Clearly, $r(r-d) > 0$ and $t >0$, and we obtain $r^2-nd > 0$, as required.